# Python Scraping Web page

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I tried to Scrap all the 'a' tag placeholder values from this sample link:https://www.fundoodata.com/companies-in/list-of-apparel-stores-companies-in-india-i239

What I need is I want to copy only the names of 'a' tag and need to save it to a csv file

I'm beginner can anyone help me out below is my wrong code:

```
# importing the modules
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time
import os


link = "https://www.fundoodata.com/companies-in/list-of-apparel-stores-companies-in-india-i239"




# instantiating empty lists
nameList = []


for i in range(1) :
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

 
    # fetching all the store details
    storeDetails = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-result')
 

 
    # iterating the storeDetails
    for j in range(len(storeDetails)):
         
        # fetching the name, address and contact for each entry
        name = storeDetails[j].find_element_by_class_name('heading').text
    
         
        myList = []
         
        nameList.append(name)


    driver.close()
 
     
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Company Name': nameList,}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
 
# Save Data as .csv
df.to_csv("D:\xxx\xxx\xx\xxx\demo.csv", mode='w+', header = False)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with your current code? What doesn't work? What error do you see and where?

Comment: this code is totally wrong

Comment: So, your question should be more focused. We are not a free coding service, we can only help with some specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems here first of which:

```
## to open webpage
driver.get(link)
```

secondly you don't need the first for loop at all. Lastly:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
## find the a tags inside the search results
storedetails = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.heading a')
## iterating over elements list
for name in storedetails:
    ## appending the a tag text
    nameList.append(name.text)
```

I hope this helped! :)